# Anti-de Sitter superalgebra from preserved symmetry

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, superalgebra

Following **Freedman & Van Proeyen's "Supergravity"**, the $\mathcal{N}=1,\, D=4$ AdS supergravity action is

$$ \dfrac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int d^4x \; e \left[R(\omega) - \bar{\psi}_\mu \gamma^{\mu \nu \rho} \hat{D}_\nu \psi_\rho + \dfrac{6}{L^2} \right], $$

where $\hat{D}_\nu \epsilon= \left(\partial_\nu + \dfrac14 \omega_{\nu a b} \gamma^{ab}-\dfrac{1}{2L}\gamma_\nu\right)\epsilon$. This action is locally supersymmetric under the transformations

$$\delta e_\mu^a = \dfrac12 \bar{\epsilon} \gamma^a \psi_\mu, \; \; \; \delta\psi_\mu=\hat{D}_\mu \epsilon,$$

and its soft algebra is given by

$$ [\delta(\epsilon_1), \delta(\epsilon_2)] e_\mu^a= (\delta_\xi - \delta_\lambda - \delta_\epsilon)e_\mu^a,$$

with $\xi^a=\dfrac12 \bar{\epsilon}_2 \gamma^a \epsilon_1$, $\lambda_{ab}=\xi^\rho \omega_{\rho a b} + \dfrac{1}{L} \bar{\epsilon}_1 \gamma_{a b} \epsilon_2$, $\epsilon=\xi^\rho \psi_\rho$.

A solution with zero fermions is given by Anti-de Sitter space. Let us look at this solution in the Poincaré patch

$$ds^2= e^{2r/L}\eta_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + dr^2,$$

with $\mu=0,1,2$. In these coordinates, the Killing spinors are:

$$\epsilon_+= e^{r/2L}\eta_+, \; \; \epsilon_-= \left(e^{-r/2L}+ \dfrac{1}{L} e^{r/2L}x^\mu\gamma_{\hat{\mu}} \right) \eta_-,$$
with $\gamma_r \eta_{\pm}= \pm \eta_{\pm}$ and hatted indices referring to flat space.

The Anti-de Sitter superalgebra for one supersymmetry generator $Q_\alpha$ is the following:
$$\begin{align}
[P_\mu, Q_\alpha]&= \dfrac{1}{4L}(\gamma_\mu Q)_\alpha,\\
\{Q_\alpha, Q_\beta\} &= -\dfrac12(\gamma^\mu)_{\alpha \beta}P_\mu - \dfrac{1}{8L}(\gamma^{\mu \nu})_{\alpha \beta} M_{\mu \nu}.\end{align}$$

My question is, how can we show that this superalgebra arises from the soft algebra for the preserved symmetries? In particular, why does the Lorentz transformations appear in the anticommutator of the fermionic generators?

Comment: I haven't done the exercise to find the $\frac{1}{8}$ coefficient, but you should always expect every term allowed by dimensional analysis to appear.

Comment: Did you make any progress towards an answer yet?